# google app engine nodejs deployment error

Tags: google-app-engine

re-deploying to app engine a project that requires node:"7.6.0" yields this error:

gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLkJe.png)

And deploying with node:"7.8.0" succeeds but with warnings:

gpg: Good signature from "Jeremiah Senkpiel "
gpg:                 aka "keybase.io/fishrock "
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDGnu.png)

Is this a GAE key management issue?

Any help would be much appreciated,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker#installing-a-different-nodejs-version), this occurs when the associated binary for the downloaded Node.js version you are using is not an officially signed Node.js release.

You can of course override the verification by using the `--ignore-verification-failure` flag during the `install_node` step in your [Dockerfile](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).

You might alternatively be able to use the `--direct` flag during the `install_node` step to download and install directly from nodejs.org instead of from https://storage.googleapis.com/gae_node_packages.